# No running micro integrator instances found. Please start a server and login

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I followed the steps for both wso2mi-4.0.0.zip & wso2mi-dashboard-4.0.0.zip mentioned in the https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/releases:

Extract the downloaded zip file.
Go to the bin directory in the extracted folder.
Run the micro-integrator.sh file if you are on a Linux/Mac OS or run the micro-integrator.bat file if you are on a Windows OS.

micro-integrator.bat for dashboard

when I login the response "No running micro integrator instances found. Please start a server and login ".Is there any missing steps ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following config in the deployment.toml of mi server.

```
[dashboard_config]
dashboard_url = "https://{hostname/ip}:{port}/dashboard/api/"
heartbeat_interval = 5
group_id = "mi_dev"
node_id = "dev_node_2"
```

Sample values are Hostname:localhost and Port:9743.

Please refer - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/observe/mi-observe/working-with-monitoring-dashboard/#step-2-configure-the-mi-servers